# How to customize ItemStyle in Announcement web part to have Read more link inside body in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have an Announcement Webpart added in my pages
I want to add Read more link blow each item
I searched the net they give this xsl code blow:

```
<xsl:template name="removeMarkup">
   <xsl:param name="string" />
   <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains($string, '&lt;')">
          <xsl:variable name="nextString">
                 <xsl:call-template name="removeMarkup">
                 <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '&gt;')" />
                 </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($string, '&lt;'), $nextString)" />
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
   </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template name="ReadMoreAnnouncements" match="Row[@Style='ReadMoreAnnouncements']" mode="itemstyle">
<br />
<div class="RMAnnouncementsTitle">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
 </div>
 <div class="RMAnnouncementsBody">
    <xsl:variable name="bodyContent">
        <xsl:call-template name="removeMarkup">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@Body"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($bodyContent,1,190)" />
    ...
    <br />
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            /Lists/Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=
            <xsl:value-of select="@ID">
            </xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            RMAnnouncementsMoreLink
        </xsl:attribute>
        read more
    </a>
 </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I have putted in my ItemStyle.xsl before

but it don't shows read more link.
please any help will be appreciated.